# Json receive a request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi i have generate this

```
 jsonWriter
     .key(FEEDBACK)
        .object()
        .key(DOCUMENT)
        .value(idDocument)
    .endObject();
```

When it come it coming something like this : {"feedback":{"document":"0.23106060923811467"}

When i try to create the object json it gives me an error:

```
    JSONTokener json = new JSONTokener(request.getParameter("id"));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That seems to be missing the closing `}`

Comment: Yes but in the javascript it returns me taht.window.open("../opendocument?id="+arguments[0].responseText)